# Who are left-most & right-most DC comics superheroes in this image?

Tags: dc, comics, character-identification, super-hero

This is the header image used in newsletter of DC comics digital store of Comixology:
[image: DC Comics Header]
Can you please identify the left-most & right-most superheroes in it?

Comment: Well, Superman is pretty conservative, and from what I understand Aquaman is part of the Occupy Gotham movement. Makes for a frosty JLA meeting with Batman.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The left-most is Aquaman, the right-most is [Cyborg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg_%28comics%29) (He's traditionally been a member of the Teen Titans).  The full line up is Aquaman, Green Lantern (Hal Jordan), Wonder Woman, Superman, Batman (Bruce Wayne), The Flash (Barry Allen), and Cyborg.

Comment: I guessed Aquaman due to his weapon.. I encountered him before in his non-shaved version, but are you certain, right-most is Cyborg? The red-orb type structure isn't supposed to be there..

Comment: @SachinShekhar The red orb is there on [this picture from the wikipedia article](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/16/Cyborg_JLA.jpg)

Comment: @SachinShekhar It's part of the redesign for the New-52.